# Working with routes.maproute and parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am have a parameter that I want to use as the default ending of a URL, but it is currently a parameter.  I want it to always direct to the Home Controller & Index Action, but the "/" becomes the pageName parameter.

For example, I want

```
http://localhost:18792/?pageName=HomePage
```

To be accessible by:

```
http://localhost:18792/HomePage
```

This is my current routes.maproute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
              url: "{controller}/{action}/{pageName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", pageName = "HomePage" }
            );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you will have to create a route for each page. Don't modify the "Default" route. . Add a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "HomePage",
    url: "HomePage",  
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HomePage" }
);
```

for dynamic routes, you could use:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PageName",
    url: "{pageName}",  
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", pageName = "defaultPage" }
);
```

which will map to ~/defaultpage or ~/homepage with the Action "Index" in the "Home" controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string pageName)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = pageName;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: The pageNames are generated dynamically though.  Isn't there a way to tell MVC that any page with just /"string" runs through the custom mapping?

Comment: added another option, but this is risky, as any string will try to match to ~/home/index/{pagename} - likely to generate a TON of 404s